# How to find first instance of a specific element at first child level

Tags: jquery

If I have the following code...

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h5>
        <div>something</div>
    </h5>
    <div>more</div>
</div>
```

...what is the easiest way to tell jquery, find the first div element at the first child level, which would be `<div>more</div>`, so that I can place a border around it?

I tried playing around with the following...

```
$('#wrapper').next('div').css({'border':'solid 2px pink'});
```

but no luck.

**FYI - I know that a div is not suppose to sit inside an h5 element, that is out of my control to modify.**

Comment: actually, in your case, `<div>something</div>` would be the first div at *child* level, wouldnt it?

Comment: I thought that was the child of h5, not the first immediate child of #wrapper.  I want to find the first div at the first child level

Comment: You should slap the bytes out of who placed a div inside a h5 tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery child selector and then :first selector from that.

- https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

`$('#wrapper>div:first').css({'border':'solid 2px pink'});`

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has **[children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)** and **[first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/)** which can help you with this.

```
$('#wrapper').children('div').first().css({'border':'solid 2px pink'});
```